# UISearchDisplayController Without Dimming?

Tags: ios, ipad

I am writing a SplitView iPad app. Inside the DetailViewController, there's a little view that contains a `UITableView` and a `UISearchBar` and its controller. This view does not represent the whole screen space reserved for the DetailViewController. Actually, it uses just half of it. There's an `UIImageView` on the other half.

And this is where trouble comes in: every time I use the search bar, the displaycontroller (I assume) dims everything present inside the DetailViewController, including the image view. That is not consistent with what someone would expect when running the app. Is there any way to set the frame to be dimmed? Or at least disable dimming for good?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You are correct that it is the UISearchDisplayController that is managing the "dimming" effect that you're seeing.

What the UISearchDisplayController is doing is adding a UIControl as a subview to the view of the searchContentsController (a property of UISearchDisplayController), which is likely your detail-view controller.  This UIControl is just an alpha'd view with a gray background.  It seems to have a touch-up-inside event handler that ends searching when tapped.

To constrain the dimming effect to your sub-view of the detail-view, you need to do three things.  (I'm assuming your detail-view-controller is defined via a xib.  If not, these steps can be done in code too.)

1) add a new UIViewController to your detail-view-controller xib.  Attach this new view-controller to an IBOutlet of your detail-view-controller.  In my example I call this "_searchAreaViewController".  This is important, even if you wont ever access the view controller (but remember, you'll have to release it at some point)

```
@interface DetailViewController : UIViewController <UIPopoverControllerDelegate, UISplitViewControllerDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource> {

    UIPopoverController *popoverController;
    UIToolbar *toolbar;

    id detailItem;
    UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;

    IBOutlet UIViewController* _searchAreaViewController;
}
```

2) make the containing view for your search area the view of this new view-controller.  To do this, use Interface Builder to set a new referencing outlet for this view by dragging the outlet to the searchAreaViewController and selecting the "view" outlet.  You must have a containing view - it should be a subview of your detail-view, and it should contain the UISearchBar and likely your UITableView.

3) make the searchContentsController property of the UISearchDisplayController refer to this new view controller instead of the detail-view-controller.   This can only be done via Interface Builder as the property is read-only (IB has some magic to make this work?)  If you need to do this step via code you'll have to subclass the UISearchDisplayController and return the correct value from a property override of "searchContentsController".

I made a sample app to demonstrate this and the only line of code I had to add to the SplitView template was the one listed in step 1 above.  Everything else was just adding the views/controllers and connecting them properly in IB.

good luck!

Comment: After doing that, the area still dims... My only doubt is on step number 2. When linking the view to the view controller, it becames an outlet for both the detail view controller and the searchAreaViewController. Is that correct? If I remove the reference to the detail view controller, the app crashes on startup.

Comment: No, it should only be the view for the new "searchAreaViewController".  This view needs to be a subview of the DetailViewController's view.  Is that what you have?

Comment: Thanks for taking your time building that sample, Tom. Now I got it right.

Comment: How come only when I add an IBOutlet for _searchAreaViewController, it works?  If I didn't, the search results won't even appear.

Comment: Hi TomSwift, you have no idea how your sample project helped me getting searchdisplaycontroller for uitable. thanks a ton. I have 2 uitableviews in single viewcontroller which ultimately covers half a screen each and I wanted to place searchdisplaycontroller for one of them. I'd tried for a month or so but some or the other how it wasm't working for me.

Answer (score 1):

iOS 8+

```
    [[UIView appearanceWhenContainedInInstancesOfClasses:@[NSClassFromString(@"UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView")]] setHidden:YES];
```

iOS 7

```
    [View appearanceWhenContainedIn:NSClassFromString(@"UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView"), nil] setHidden:YES];
```

I know, that UISearchDisplayController is deprecated for now, but if you still need to use it, you can solve your issue with one line of code perfectly. Add it to viewDidLoad method.

Comment: This answer does not appear to add anything significant to the question.  If this is discussing new changes that other developers need to watch out for since the other answers have been posted, please make that abundantly clear in your answer since this question is so old. Better yet, suggest an edit to the appropriate answer to update it.

Comment: @Ghedipunk, I think you are wrong and this answer adds something significant, because other developers now could not to spend much time struggling and implementing so many steps as before. P.S. Answer was updated.

Comment: Then use more than 2 lines of code and a poorly written paragraph to explain why this adds something significant.

Comment: The answer _may_ be right, but it is not _helpful_. Please take a few minutes to edit this answer in order to walk the user through how to use these lines of code and what the benefits are.  This is an old question, so extra care should be taken for new questions.

Answer (score 0):

Could you clarify what you mean by "use the search bar" and "dims everything present"? I interpret what you wrote in such a way that the keyboard pops up when you are about to enter text in the text field of the search bar. And that at this point the detail view is dimmed out, preventing user interaction.

The cause is that the search bar implements a modal dialog which prevents user interaction with the view as long as the keyboard is shown. Unfortunately, there doesn't seem to be any way to configure the search bar to prevent this behavior. On the other hand I am not sure that the user won't expect this behavior since search bars are modal consistently and behave like this in general under iOS.

I have tried two work-arounds:

1.) There is a property of the `UIViewController` called `modalPresentationStyle` which produces exactly the behavior you describe if it has the value `UIModalPresentationFormSheet` ("All uncovered areas are dimmed to prevent the user from interacting with them.", see the [Apple documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UIViewController_Class/Reference/Reference.html)). But setting this property to a different values does not change the result (at least for me it didn't work).

2.) You would need to write your own non-modal search bar replacement since a standard UITextField is non-modal and thus does not dim out any other UI elements. This approach works, but you might need a little more work to make it look like a "regular" search bar. But, again, since this search bar behaves differently from the modal normal search bars in iOS this might not really be what the users expect.

Answer (score 0):

I know I am late and this is a horrible idea here, but 'setHidden:No' did not work for me.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText
{

BOOL hasBeenremoved = NO;
hasBeenremoved = [[[[NSThread mainThread] threadDictionary] objectForKey:@"hasBeenremoved"] boolValue];

if (hasBeenremoved)
{
    UIView* dimmingView = nil;
    dimmingView = [[[NSThread mainThread] threadDictionary] objectForKey:@"dimmingView"];

    UIView* dimmingViewSuperView = nil;
    dimmingViewSuperView = [[[NSThread mainThread] threadDictionary] objectForKey:@"dimmingViewSuperView"];

    [dimmingViewSuperView addSubview:dimmingView];

    [[[NSThread mainThread] threadDictionary] setObject:@NO forKey:@"hasBeenremoved"];
}

if ([searchText length] == 0 || [searchText isEqualToString:@""] )
   {
       [searchBar becomeFirstResponder];
       [[[self primarySearchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] reloadData];
       [[[self primarySearchDisplayController] searchResultsTableView] setHidden:NO];

       for( UIView *subview in self.view.subviews )
       {
           if([subview  isMemberOfClass:[UIControl class]] ||
              ([[[subview  class] description] isEqualToString:@"UISearchDisplayControllerContainerView"]))

           {
               for(UIView *subView2 in subview.subviews)
               {
                   for(UIView *subView3 in subView2.subviews)
                   {
                       if (subView3.alpha < 1)
                       {


                           if ([[[subView3 class] description] isEqualToString:@"_UISearchDisplayControllerDimmingView"])
                           {
                               [[[NSThread mainThread] threadDictionary] setObject:subView3 forKey:@"dimmingView"];
                               [[[NSThread mainThread] threadDictionary] setObject:subView3.superview forKey:@"dimmingViewSuperView"];

                               [[[NSThread mainThread] threadDictionary] setObject:@YES forKey:@"hasBeenremoved"];

                               [subView3 removeFromSuperview];
                           }


                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
}
```