# UISearchDisplayController frame for UITableView in iOS

Tags: iphone, ios, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

- I have a `UITable` that has a `UISearchDisplayController`.
- The `UITable` is less than the width of the screen (it's 280px width centered).
- When I tap on the `search bar`, the `UISearchDisplayController` table is all the way to the left of the screen.
- Even when changing the frame of the table of the `UISearchDisplayController`, I still get the same positioning.

I set the frame here:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didLoadSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  {
    tableView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:29.0/255.0 green:30.0/255.0 blue:32.0/255.0 alpha:1];
    tableView.rowHeight = self.myTable.rowHeight;
    tableView.frame = myTable.frame;
    NSLog(@"search table origin: %f",tableView.frame.origin.x);
}
```

Even weirder, when I log the search table position at the end, it shows 16. However, it is at position 0 in the view.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: This answer from Tom Swift solved my problem: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4128659/675486

Answer (score 20, accepted):

I answered my own question. The frame needs to be set in this delegate method:

```
- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView  {

    tableView.frame = self.myTable.frame;

}
```

Comment: Thank you, was about to just create my own table view because I wanted to move it slightly below the search bar and could not find a clean way to do it.

Comment: Thanks, it helped me but leaves at least 2 problems open: when rotating device, bar fits the whole screen width, and when closing animation is ugly, it flashes to the whole width again.

Answer (score 1):

Try this Simple Method:

```
//--Search display controller frame

- (void)searchDisplayController:(UISearchDisplayController *)controller didShowSearchResultsTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    CGRect statusBarFrame =  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] statusBarFrame];

    [tableView setFrame:CGRectMake(my_table.frame.origin.x, tableView.frame.origin.y, my_table.frame.size.width, my_table.frame.size.height)];

}
```