# IOS Customizing UISearchBar and Search Display

Tags: ios, storyboard, uisearchbar, uisearchdisplaycontroller

Hey I have been trying to customize a UISearch bar with display controller and have run into some issues customizing certain aspects of the search and display controllers.  I'm using storyboard and am developing with the most recent version of IOS 6.

The first issue is eliminating the dark grey gradient overlay that appears when you first click on the search text view.  I have tried to use the `searchDisplayController:willShowSearchResultsTableView:` delegate but am unable to either find the view that is being used as the gradient overlay or a property to disable it.  How do I remove this view?

The second is I am having an issue with the initial animation that is triggered when the search view is clicked. The animation is supposed to expand the search bar over the UINavigationBar to allow for a larger space to view the results.  This doesn't happen and the search bar stays below the UINavigationBar and the animation doesn't properly show.  I have tried setting the `displaysSearchBarInNavigationBar` and `navigationItem` properties but couldn't find any way to access or set them.  Could this be an issue with the fact that I'm using autolayout in my story board?  I have noticed that many issues relating to the UISearchBar animations are due to autolayout being used in the .xib or storyboard file.  How can I make it correctly over the navigation bar?

The third issue I am having is with over ridding the `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:(UISearchBar *)searchBar` delegate method.  I have subclassed the UISearchBar to allow for complete customization.  Is there a way to provide a default definition for the `searchBarTextDidBeginEditing:` delegate method inside my custom UISearchBar subclass.  I want to provide a specific style of text in the UITextView when the user clicks on the search bar and don't want to have to redefine this method in every view controller that uses the search bar.  Is this possible?

Thanks for the help in solving these issues.

Comment: For your first question, check out this answer:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3527927/uisearchdisplaycontroller-without-dimming

Comment: Yeah I figured out all of the issues I will post my answer soon!