# How to make the surrounding of UISeachBar still active when entering text

Tags: ios, objective-c, uisearchbar

Referring to screenshot below, when I started to type in the search bar, the below view of the search bar become grey out and inactive. How to disable such property? This is the [full code](https://github.com/zonble/MOEDict/blob/master/MOEDict/MDViewController.m).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

`UISearchDisplayController` is deprecated from iOS 8, so if you want to update the source code, please use `UISearchController` and set `dimsBackgroundDuringPresentation` = false

In case you still want to maintain the source code, there's no official solution. That's because "dim" effect was managed by `UISearchDisplayController` and Apple didn't expose any methods to remove it. There are some hack solutions but it cannot work well in next iOS versions, unless you make a searchController by yourself.

In summary, you should use `UISearchController` instead of `UISearchDisplayController`. It'll take some time at first, but you don't need worry about it anymore.

Answer (score 0):

Below link may be resolved your issue

https://stackoverflow.com/a/4128659/5184217